# Python Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm playing with querysets in django.

What I'm looking it's to save a new foreign product or item but I can not achieve it.

*shell*

```
from applaboratorio.models import Datos_empresa_DB, Datos_equipo_DB

detalle = Datos_empresa_DB.objects.filter(pk=58)

resp = Datos_equipo_DB(equipo='dell-labtop',marca='dell', modelo='432423',Foraneo_Datos_empresa_DB = detalle)
```

***models.py***

```
class Datos_empresa_DB(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Datos_equipo_DB(models.Model):
    Foraneo_Datos_empresa_DB = models.ForeignKey(Datos_empresa_DB)
    equipo = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

What am I doing bad?

I'm trying to create a new product for a client that already exist in db.

Comment: You should include your models definition so we can tell what is the shape of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're nearly there. You need to call the `save` method of the new product to *save* to the DB, and to *retrieve* the related client object, you should `get` not `filter` so you have the object itself and not a list of objects (or *QuerySet*):

```
detalle = Datos_empresa_DB.objects.get(pk=58)
#                                  ^^^
resp = Datos_equipo_DB(equipo='dell-labtop',marca='dell', modelo='432423',Foraneo_Datos_empresa_DB =detalle)
#                                          Save on model's related field <-^^^^^^^
resp.save()
```

Comment: This. Or, alternatively, `resp = Datos_empresa_DB.objects.create(equipo='dell-labtop', marca='dell', modelo='432423', detalle=detalle)`

Comment: @spectras Yes, that too :)

Comment: Are you sure guys?

Comment: @Elarquitecto Change `detalle` to `Foraneo_Datos_empresa_DB` in the model instantiation